# Empty result when filter by NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a customized object called MyContact, there are two parameters inside, one is name(NSString), the other is phoneArray(NSArray). I generated a MyContact array and used NSPredicate with "phoneArray contains %@" to filter, I got empty result, but when I used "name contains %@" to filter, I can get correct result.I don't know why. Following is my demo code!

```
@interface MyContact : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *phoneArray;

@end

@autoreleasepool {

    NSMutableArray *myContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    MyContact *contact1 = [[MyContact alloc] init];
    contact1.name = @"will mo";
    contact1.phoneArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"138761", nil];
    [myContacts addObject:contact1];
    [contact1 release];

    MyContact *contact2 = [[MyContact alloc] init];
    contact2.name = @"robert jiang";
    contact2.phoneArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"13554227",   @"876368268", nil];
    [myContacts addObject:contact2];
    [contact2 release];

    MyContact *contact3 = [[MyContact alloc] init];
    contact3.name = @"watson song";
    contact3.phoneArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"73514637", @"6216738", nil];
    [myContacts addObject:contact3];
    [contact3 release];

    MyContact *contact4 = [[MyContact alloc] init];
    contact4.name = @"marco sch";
    contact4.phoneArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"42437845", nil];
    [myContacts addObject:contact4];
    [contact4 release];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phone contains %@", @"24"];
    NSArray *resultArray = [myContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@", resultArray);

    [myContacts release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"phoneArray" is an *array* of strings. To check if any of the array elements contains
the given string, use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY phoneArray CONTAINS %@", @"24"];
```